# Find the domain on which $\log(z^2+9)$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following function

$$f(z)=\log(z^2+9)$$

I need to find the set on which this function is analytic.

So far I know that $\log(z)$ is analytic in $D= \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z \notin (-\infty, 0] \right \}$.

So, I understand that for my function $D= \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z^2+9 \notin (-\infty, 0] \right \} = \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z^2 \notin (-\infty, -9] \right \}$.

How should I continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z^2 \notin (-\infty, -9] \right \}$ is a perfectly good specification of the set, so you could reasonably stop here. However, if you'd prefer an interval form, note that $z^2 \in (-\infty, -9]$ means $z$ is purely imaginary and has imaginary part at least $3$ or no more than $-3$. Thus $D$ is the union of two rays:
$$
D = \{z\in \mathbb C | iz\notin (-\infty, -3]\} \cup \{z\in \mathbb C | iz\notin[3,\infty)\} 
$$

Comment: did you meant: $D = \left \{ z \in \mathbb(c) | iz \notin (-\infty, -3] \right \} \cup  \left \{ z \in \mathbb(c) | iz \notin (\infty, 3] \right \}$ ?

Comment: @David Yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "the" set on which the function is analytic/holomorphic, perhaps contrary to some introductory situations in which the complex plane is almost-always "slit" along the negative real axis, or other iconic things.

To begin with, for example, (the collection of local pieces of) $\log z$ *is* holomorphic at points on the negative real axis, perhaps contrary to some (too-naive) knee-jerk slittings-of-the-plane along the negative real axis. In fact, in some neighborhood of *every* point in $\mathbb C$ except $0$, there is a functions $g(z)$ such that $e^{g(z)}=z$.

The *real* point is best understood, at least in the long run, in terms of the Monodromy Theorem, which deserves more discussion than I should do here.

In the case at hand, a function $\log(z^2+9)=\log(z+3i)+\log(z+3i)$ is *locally* defined (in the sense that it exponentiates to $z^2+9$) at any point other than $\pm 3i$. Period.

The implicit meaning of the question is finding a (not "the") *maximal* open set on which there is such a function. With a heuristic notion of Monodromy, the point is that we have to choose a region so that we cannot (for example) go in a closed path around either $\pm 3i$ (at least without also going around the other), because that would add $\pm 2\pi i$ to one of the logs while not changing the other.

One way to do this is to choose a region that does not include any closed path around either $\pm 3i$, e.g., "slitting" the plane from both of the points out to infinity (perhaps not allowing the two slits to intersect, just to avoid technicalities). The slits need not be straight lines...

EDIT: I'd earlier claimed that a "slit" between the two branch points $\pm 3i$ would suffice, but @Maxim observed that my argument was incorrect, since (I add this because the general idea is certainly of interest) going around both $\pm 3i$ does *not* cancel out the ambiguities in $\log$, since both are in the same orientation.

(Thanks again to @Maxim for observing my inaccuracy!!!)

Comment: There is another interpretation, which is that $\log$ is the principal value of the logarithm, and the question is about where $\log(z^2 + 9)$ with this fixed branch of $\log$ is analytic. This is unambiguous. Regardless of interpretation, it's not true that there is a branch of $\log(z^2 + 9)$ which is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [-3 i, 3 i]$.

Comment: @Maxim, well, ok, if the question is about where a pre-specified version of log-whatever is holomorphic, that's indeed a different thing that what I addressed. On another hand, unless I'm doing a brain-fade, which is always possible, the reason I gave explains why removing a path between $\pm 3i$ trivializaes the monodromy, so there's a "global" (in a relative sense) function. Or maybe I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: The issue is that we're circling around $3i$ and $-3i$ in the same direction, so the imaginary part changes by $4 \pi$ ($\infty$ is a branch point of $\log(z^2 + 9)$).

Comment: @Maxim, ah, indeed, "my bad"...